# React: Can't find firebase stored data to use as object in json

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a `POST` request to store data to the firebase, the data is getting stored in the firebase correctly but while trying to access the properties & writing `response.json()` it's not showing the object data in the console it's undefined`.

I'm trying to store users' data and make the list of entered users. After submitting the form the data will send as object to parent `addedUser(userData);`

Now parent comp is using `addUser`

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

const recieveUserData = async (users) => {
        setUserData((items) => [users, ...items]);

        const responseData = await fetch(
            "https://user-entry-data-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(users),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            }
        );

        const data = await responseData.json();

        //showing fine with correct encrypt name but missing object data
        console.log(data);
        //showing undefined
        console.log(data.userName);
    };
//JSX
<AddUserForm addedUser={recieveUserData} />
//User list wrapper component
<Users newUser={userData} />
```

List is coming fine

[image]

Data is stored in firebase

[image]

But after submitting the form getting this error and undefined values

[image]

You can check my [Complete code](https://github.com/mohitdevelops/user-entry/tree/main/src)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually working as intended:

```
//showing undefined
console.log(data.userName);
```

If you check carefully, the JSON you get back from the database has multiple users. So your `data` is a list of users, and the list itself does't have a `name` property.

If you want to log the name for all users in the list:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
   console.log(data[key].userName);
});
```